# What were "printing tokens" used for?

Tags: metaplex, nft, metadata

I noticed in the token metadata program that there [were deprecated ixs](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/instruction.rs) to create "printing tokens" from a master edition.

It seems like the current standard can mint a new edition directly from the master edition.

After some sleuthing I found [this tx](https://solscan.io/tx/5M8ve56cbW1YhaEDkeVR2k3EQjzrfFtAZyGePuybmJS5dC3mkL9P71LatQdQj2a6mbBukuVsjmLKFBbQvSDjKboX) that used `DeprecatedMintPrintingTokens` and `DeprecatedMintNewEditionFromMasterEditionViaPrintingToken`.

Interestingly the printing token is immediately burned in `DeprecatedMintNewEditionFromMasterEditionViaPrintingToken` in that instruction.

Are printing tokens just a relic of the old program, and are not actually tokens the end user interacts with?

Answer (score 1):

The Master Edition account also allows users to print one or multiple copies of an NFT.

This feature is particularly helpful to creators that want to offer multiple copies of their 1/1 NFTs to their audience.

The Master Edition account contains an optional Max Supply attribute that dictates the maximum amount of NFTs that can be printed that way. If set to 0, printing is disabled. If set to None an unlimited amount of copies can be printed.

Details on print editions can be found [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview#printing-editions)

Comment: This seems to be related to the new edition standard where one can directly make a copy (edition) from a master edition. What I'm curious about is why a temporary printing token was required in the past?